# OWASP ZAP integration into SOAPUI for REST API Testing

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, api-testing, security-testing, penetration

One of the topics I am currently working on is the testing of APIs on the security level, e.g. as integration in SOAPUI and OWASP in WSO2.
The integration of SOAPUI and WSO2 is set up and also works. Unfortunately I haven't found a reasonable manual to help me with the point OWASP ZAP on REST API level.

OWASP currently offers only [this information](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_SaaS_Rest_API_Secure_Guide) which does not help me. In the further references which I link here, this topic is not talked past but no corresponding solution is offered.

Do you have tips on Soap UI or REST API Penetration Test or SoapUI Security Checks, or articles or helpful information on how I could integrate them?

References:

1. [OWASP Secure Coding Practices](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Coding_Practices_-_Quick_Reference_Guide)
2. [Oracle Secure Coding Guidelines for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)
3. [SANS Secure Coding Guidelines](https://www.sans.org/course/secure-coding-java-jee-developing-defensible-applications)
4. [Static Code Analysis for Java using FindBugs Plugin and Identifying Security Bugs with FindSecurityBugs Plugin](http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/06/static-code-analysis-for-java-using.html)
5. [OWASP Dependency Check CLI – Analyzing Vulnerabilities in 3rd Party Libraries](http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/10/owasp-dependency-check-cli-analyzing.html)
6. [Checking vulnerabilities in 3rd party dependencies using OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin in Jenkins](https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/checking-vulnerabilities-in-3rd-party-dependencies-using-owasp-dependency-check-plugin-in-jenkins-bedfe8de6ba8#.ipu0b8u4o)
7. [Dynamic Scanning with OWASP ZAP for Identifying Security Threats](https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/dynamic-scanning-with-owasp-zap-for-identifying-security-threats-complete-guide-52b3643eee04#.nyy1fwiok)
8. [Automating the boring stuff in development using ZAP and Jenkins : Continuous Integration](https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/automating-the-boring-stuffs-using-zap-and-jenkins-continues-integration-d4461a6ace1a#.jtknrzajt)

Answer (score -1):

Now I solved that problem by myself, these attached links describe my problem exactly. Apparently, I simply thought too broadly and did not recognize the problem immediately.

https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/automating-the-boring-stuffs-using-zap-and-jenkins-continues-integration-d4461a6ace1a#.jtknrzajt

http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/

https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/automating-security-testing-of-web-applications-using-owasp-zed-attack-proxy-in-jenkins-aa0f9eafdcba#.oysiaj8fm